# Custom Validation in jQuery Unobtrusive Validation Without Field Name

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, asp.net-core-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

Is it possible, using jQuery unobtrusive validation, to specify a custom validation function that is not bound to a specific field? I mean, a validation function that is triggered when the form is validated, but not targeted at a specific form field.
This is in the context of ASP.NET Core validation, and I would prefer not to add any code to the form submit handler.
Essentially, I would like to keep the default behavior when I click on a submit button, but besides the usual field-oriented validation also do bespoke ("global") validation too.

Comment: it is possible, you cann call whatever function you want on form submit

Comment: Of course I can. I should have made myself cleared: I'm talking in the context of ASP.NET Core client-side validation. Updated the question.

Comment: Possible to trigger a function on form valid and/or form invalid.  Not possible to have a validation rule not tied to a specific field(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to have an hidden field with validation attributes:

```
<input type="hidden" id="val" name="val" data-val="true" data-val-custom="My custom error message" />
```

Then hook it to unobtrusive validation:

```
$.validator.addMethod('custom', function (value, element, params) {
    //whatever
    return false;
});
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool('custom');
```

This way it will *appear* as if it is general, not field-specific.